# translate curl command to python module request is not working

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

My Problem is as follows:
i have a working curl expression but i am not able to translate it into my python code

My curl command looks like this:

```
curl --cert-type P12 --cert "path-to-cert.p12":password -u username:password jenkins-url
```

working with a certificate which has a password seems to be difficult.
Has someone a tip for me or another solution then "request"

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at translating it to python :)

Comment: sry for that... 

cert = 'path-to-cert.p12:password'

response = requests.get('http://jenkins-url', cert=cert, auth=('username', 'password'))

that was the attempt but it doesnt recognize the password